# Draw a dynamic graph in python

Tags: python, drawing

I have a hard time finding a `python` code example that draws a **graph structure** (like a tree / state machine) and which you can **feed/stream data** to, so that it plots the most recent data.

Comment: put the data in a textfile FIFO style, Parse it using python and draw you graph. Then have a cron-job that does this once every n-th second while some other process puts data in the textfile.

Comment: try [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/)

Comment: @fredrik well the problem is that every time there is a new plot, a new image appears. I want one window that is adjusted

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, this code should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys
import threading
import time

import networkx as nx # http://networkx.github.com/
import xdot # http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/XDot
import gtk

class MyClass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.graph = nx.DiGraph(name="my_tree")
        self.xdot = xdot.DotWindow()
        self.xdot.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)

    def run(self):
        gtk.main()

    def add_node(self, parent, node):

        self.graph.add_edge(parent, node)
        self.xdot.set_dotcode(nx.to_agraph(self.graph).to_string())
        self.xdot.show_all()

def main(argv=None):

    gtk.gdk.threads_init()
    my_class = MyClass()
    my_class.start()

    my_class.add_node(1, 2)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    my_class.add_node(1, 3)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    my_class.add_node(2, 4)
    time.sleep(1.3)
    my_class.add_node(2, 5)
    my_class.add_node(1, 6)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going with updating a file, then reading it from a separate process periodically, you might want to consider just writing a simple web server and using your browser as a UI, then using JSON, with the client requesting data periodically.

Have you considered using [IPython](http://ipython.org/)? Their HTML Notebook has really good support for rendering with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). You may still have to do some JavaScript to get what you want, but they've done a lot of work there that's available on the devs' GitHub accounts and stuff, but not in master yet.

They have a Qt Console as well, which might be better able to do what you want.

Comment: I don't want to rely on a web server, I want a file I can execute and run.

Comment: I web server is a file you can execute, which means the same thing as run.